useState length always = 1 when search box is empty
I have a small issue related to some basic search box logic which returns results from Firebase.
The issue is related to my useState query. When the page is loaded the state is set to the correct initial state which is an empty string. When typing in the search box the onChange handler gets updated as expected and runs the function for the search.
However, when all characters are removed from the search box, the state of query still holds onto the last character. For example
if you search 'Car' in the search box and then remove all characters, the search state will hold onto 'C' therefore running the function whilst the front end shows an empty search box
Code below



const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([])
const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState('')

const handleSearch = async (query) => {
    const results = [];
    if (query) {
        setSearchQuery(query);
        try {
            const prod = await firestore.collection('products').get();
            prod.docs.forEach((doc) => {
                const searchableIndex = doc.data().searchableIndex;
                if (searchableIndex) {
                    // Convert the search query to lowercase for case-insensitive matching
                    const lowerCaseQuery = query.toLowerCase();
                    // Check if any key in the searchableIndex contains the search query as a substring
                    if (Object.keys(searchableIndex).some(key => key.includes(lowerCaseQuery))) {
                        results.push({
                            title: doc.data().title
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
            setSearchResults(results);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching products:', error);
        }
    } else {
        setSearchResults([]);
        setSearchQuery('')
        console.log(searchResults.length)
    }
};

useEffect(() => {
}, [searchResults, searchQuery, handleSearch]);

return (
<>
            <Animatable.View animation={'slideInUp'} duration={800} style={styles.searchContainer}>
                <View style={styles.searchIconContainer}>
                    <AntDesign style={{paddingLeft: 10, color: "#37BD6B"}} name="search1" size={19} />
                </View>

                <TextInput onChangeText={(e) => handleSearch(e)} autoFocus={true} style={styles.searchBar}/>
            </Animatable.View>

 <View>
                {searchResults.map((seller, index) => (
                    <View key={index} style={{backgroundColor: 'grey', padding: 15, }}>
                        <Text>{seller.title}</Text>
                        <Text>{seller.accountNumber}</Text>
                    </View>
                ))}
            </View>
</>
)


console.log(setSearchResults.length) You're checking the length of the function, not the length of the state. This is telling you the number of arguments that setSearchResults expects.

If you change it to log out searchResults.length, be aware that searchResults contains a snapshot of the previous state, not the next state. So the fact that you just set the state to an empty array won't change the log. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately

Thanks - i had just realised once i posted. How can the issue with the searchQuery be tackled?

@CodingJunkie: When you debug, what specific "issue with the searchQuery" do you observe and where specifically do you observe it?  Can you narrow down the problem you're trying to describe to the specific line(s) of code where it occurs?

As explained in the post, if a value is typed in the search box and then all characters are then deleted. The searchQuery hangs onto the last character despite the search box being empty. This is reflected from the 'else' statement where both the query and result are set to an empty string and array.  searchResults returns with a length of 1 (also tried with searchQuery)
